# Extension Submission Expired in magento marketplace

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

we are develop magento 2 extension and posted to magento market place, they are  approved **Business Review**.

After that we have some development with our extension, we doesn't post our code for **technical review** over a month. Now I check our **market place account**, our extension removed, I got mail from us,

> Rejected from Biz Rev (Submission Expired from Approved from Business Review): This submission was Approved from Business Review over a month ago. As you did not submit code to move this product further (into Technical Review) we cannot review it any further. We have assumed it has been abandoned and thus we have rejected this product. If you wish to proceed with this product after all, please resubmit to business review.

**Is there any time limit to submitting steps like business, technical?**

and

**Is there any way to post code directly to Technical review, because our extension Approved Business Review before?**

Answer (score 5):

You must follow all step one by one, You cannot post code directly to Technical review even extension is Approved in Business Review.

At the time of **Technical review**, marketplace checks coding standards, warnings, and errors and generate a report.

And at the time of **Business Review** they are not checking your extension package. They only check your module's descriptions, release, etc..

**After approving Business Review and technical review, You need to submit your package within 1 month otherwise your module will reject and you need to submit again from the first step.**

Now your module will go to **QA review**.

After approving QA review Your module will go to **Marketing Review**. At this time you need to submit module's details like

- Product Image
- Thumbnail Image
- Youtube Video
- Version Information
- Categories
- Magento Editions
- Support Browser
- Documentation
- Licence Type
- Installation Details and Price
- Support Details and Price etc......

There are so many steps for approving your module to the marketplace. I think they need to reduce step for approving modules.

Comment: They are not mentioned any time limit in technical review  documentation http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/extension-submit-technical-review.html

Comment: As per mail, he does not provide a time limit for technical review submission. `Our quality and engineering staff are examining and testing your code. We'll approve your application or list any issues that need to be fixed.`

Comment: @Prince Patel my extension is rejected from market place and when i am download report it shows 5 warning. my question is magento 2 marketplace reject extension because of warning ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil Marketplace does not reject module if you have only 5 warnings. You can see the specific reason for rejection in your email.

Comment: @PrincePatel  you mean extension is not rejected because of warning am i right ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil Yes, your extension is not rejected because of warnings. Because I uploaded extensions with 12 to 15 warnings and it's approved.

Comment: @PrincePatel  Thanks for your suggestion.